# How to Clone a child of an abstract class in WP7 XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm working on a game for WP7 with XNA.  Here is my structure:

```
public abstract class enemy
{}
```

Child elements:

```
public class genericEnemy : enemy{}
...
public class snake : enemy {}
```

etc...

In WP7, a lot of things have been moved around and/or removed (especially with Serialization) it seems.  Despite much searching, I haven't been able to find a solution.  I'm trying to duplicate the child elements.

For example:  On loading a level, I pass an array of three different enemies into the loading phase.  During loading, I need to duplicate each of those enemies so that 20 of each are flying around doing their own thing during gameplay.

All the solutions I've seen refer to things that are not present in the WP7 library.

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to access their public properties and just copy them? Or alternatively, could you edit the class definitions to add a .Clone() method? (also what do you mean by child elements?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an enemy factory that can create enemies from an id of some sorts. While loading your level, you can then call the factory when you need to create an enemy:

```
class EnemyFactory
{
 Enemy CreateEnemy(int id)
 {
  if (id == 0)
   return new Snake();
  return new GenericEnemy();
 }

}


void LoadLevel()
{
 // bla bla
 Level level = new Level();
 int enemyId = LoadFromFile();
 level.AddEnemy(EnemyFactory.CreateEnemy(enemyId));
}
```

This way you get rid of the nasty cloning code, and you can control all enemy instantiation in the factory class.

Comment: I had initially structure my code this way, but was hoping for a simpler route. After research, this does seem to be the easiest way to accomplish what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "library" way of doing this as far as I know. One solution would be:

1) Declare a Clone() method in enemy that returns a copy of that enemy.

```
abstract class Enemy {
     public abstract Enemy Clone();
}
```

2) Implement it in every concrete type, so a Snake creates a new Snake, etc. Example:

```
class Snake : Enemy {
     int speed;
     public override void Enemy Clone() {
         var clone = new Snake();
         clone.speed = speed;
         return clone;
     }
}
```

3) Now any object of a concrete type knows how to clone itself, so if you have an array of Enemies, you can call Clone() on each and it will create the proper concrete type in the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

use an abstract method that calls a copy constructor:

```
public abstract class Enemy
{
   private readonly int mEnemyData;

   protected Enemy(Enemy pEnemy)
   {
      mEnemyData = pEnemy.mEnemyData;
   }

   public abstract Enemy Clone();
}

public sealed class GenericEnemy : Enemy
{
   private readonly double mGenericEnemyData;

   private GenericEnemy(GenericEnemy pGenericEnemy)
    : base(pGenericEnemy)
   {
      mGenericEnemyData = pGenericEnemy.mGenericEnemyData;
   }

   public override Enemy Clone()
   {
      return new GenericEnemy(this);
   }
}
```